# How to efficiently execute Postgresql query using Npgsql over a high latency connection?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ssh, tcp, npgsql

I'm having some trouble when I select large tables full of strings data using Npgsql over a high latency connection (200-300 ms).
The total fields value size is something like 256kb. 
I'm totally sure that the problem is related to the transfer over the network beacause if I execute the same query locally it's executed in very short time (10 ms - 20 ms), instead if the query is executed via the slow connection it takes 20-30 seconds.
Also if i'm measuring the table using length(fields) the query is executed in a decent time (1-2 seconds).
I'm experiencing this problem on different pc, different postgresql version and npgsql.
I think that the problem is related to the size of packets.. maybe increasing the buffer could solve my problem but, how to do it? in postgres? or in npgsql?

Comment: Is it latency, bandwidth, or both that's limited? I'd use Wireshark to take a packet trace. Then use it to get statistics on the transfer and graph it.

Comment: It is latency. I'm sure of it. I also simulate the problem by tunneling the connection to my home and back again to the work pc. The bandwith it's good.

Comment: As I'm expecting using wireshark I can see, for a single query, over 200 packets of maximum 1250 bytes length.. A lot of packets in low latency connection is a bad thing.. Isn't there a way to increase the packet size?

Comment: Lots of small packets is fine, and not a big concern for latency. That's normal. They get pipelined. 1250 is a reasonable size for Internet traffic. Even on a local wired Ethernet the packet size limit is 1500 bytes unless your devices, switches, etc all support jumbo frames. Small packets are only an issue if there's a forced round trip between each, where the client waits until the server responds. TCP/IP uses smart ACKs that mean this isn't required for the low level TCP stream, only if the application forces it.

Comment: Ok, then probably it's a problem of Postgresql that is not optimized for high latency connection. Probably it has a lot of requests/waits between server and client..

Comment: What you should do is use Wireshark's PostgreSQL protocol dissector to view the PostgreSQL protocol exchange. Also view the traffic flow, see if there are regular pauses between client and server messages. PostgreSQL *is* very much optimised for high latency connections, and the protocol supports a lot of pipelining even between queries. npgsql may not use all those abilities, but it shouldn't be doing round-trips while fetching query results. There's no rational reason it should have to since receiving results is just "read the socket until the server stops sending"

Comment: I've also tried directly pgadmin, without using npgsql libs and the problem remain the same. Locally I can select all the rows in 200ms; via the ssh tunnel the query takes 17754ms. Maybe it's a problem of the tunnel... dunno. I tried to use the wireshark dissector but it doesn't get the packets because the connection is tunneled. I can see packets by filtering on the 5432 port of the server and I can see 100ms of packets, then 10 seconds of pause, then the response is coming back in 7 seconds of packets

Answer (score 2):

Per comments, you're using an SSH tunnel.

TCP-in-TCP tunneling like SSH does is absolutely awful for carrying lots of data. Expect it to perform terribly. Congestion control and window scaling don't work properly, retransmits are a problem, reordering and reassembly is inefficient, slow-start doesn't work well, etc.

Just don't do that. Use direct TCP/IP with SSL, or use a UDP-based tunnel/VPN.

PostgreSQL's protocol is quite friendly to pipelining and it requires zero round trips per field or per row fetched when getting results. You just keep reading until there's nothing more to read. So round-trip latencies shouldn't be the issue here.

It's very likely to be problems caused by the tunnel.